# How to stop TimeSensor in VRML

Tags: vrml

I'm studying VRML as a beginner. I have a problem with TimeSensor that need help. This is my source code

```
DEF time TimeSensor
{
loop TRUE
cycleInterval 2
}
DEF C11 Transform
{
translation -3 0 0
children
[
       Shape
       {
        geometry Sphere
        {
          radius 0.5
        }
        appearance Appearance
        {
          material Material
          {
             diffuseColor 0 0 0
             specularColor .29 .3 .29
             shininess .08
             ambientIntensity 0
             transparency 0.0
          } 
        }
       }

     DEF moveC11 PositionInterpolator
     {
         key [0 1]
         keyValue [-3 0 0,3 3 0]
     }
]
}
ROUTE time.fraction_changed TO moveC11.set_fraction
ROUTE moveC11.value_changed TO C11.translation
```

When I view in browser, the sphere moves from coordinate -3 0 0 to 3 3 0 and repeat.I want it moves only 1 time. The sphere stop at coordinate 3 3 0. How can I do it?

Thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 1):

### VRML concept of TimeSensor is other than to stop an infinite loop

A reverse logic works:

**Modify** `DEF time TimeSensor { loop FALSE }` to avoid uncontrollable infinite loop.

**Send** an event set_startTime with the current time to the `TimeSensor`.

The problem with this approach might be how to compute the absolute current time in seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00.

Fortunately all sensors in VRML generate events which output a time value when they **become active**.

So basically all you have to do is to `ROUTE` the event generated by the sensor when it becomes active to the `eventIn` of the `TimeSensor set_startTime`.